# C# CheckBox Checked Value is incorrect

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012, checkbox

This is driving me nuts. I have a simple CheckBox that, when checked, is suppose to do some extra work when a button is pressed. If the CheckBox is not selected, it does not do the extra work. Simple, you'd think.

```
private void previewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(mfsCheckbox.CheckState.ToString());
    if (mfsCheckbox.CheckState == CheckState.Checked)
    {
        //never gets here
        //do extra stuff
    }
    if (mfsCheckbox.Checked)
    {
        //never gets here
        //do extra stuff
    }
}

private void mfsCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(mfsCheckbox.CheckState.ToString());
    if (mfsCheckbox.Checked)
    {
        mfsCheckbox.Checked = true;
        mfsCheckbox.CheckState = CheckState.Checked;
    }
}
```

When running this code, I select the CheckBox and, per the CheckChanged event code, it says "Checked". For good measure, I even set both states in the CheckChanged event to ensure that they are set appropriately. Then, I click the preview button directly after it has just told me the CheckBox was "Checked" and it says "Unchecked" and does not run my if statement...

Basically, it goes from Checked to Unchecked even when I can visually see that it is still checked and after I've programmatically ensured it's state should be "checked".

Thanks for any help.

***UPDATE: INITIALIZECOMPONENT BEING CALLED IN ANOTHER MODULE BY STRAY CODE. I WILL PUT INTERN RESPONSIBLE ON NIGHTLY SERVER BUILD DUTY FOR LIFE AS PUNISHMENT. VOTING TO CLOSE AS THIS HAS NO VALUE FOR ANYONE ELSE.***

Comment: If i'm not mistaking the value of the checkbox is not yet set in the event handler. Could this be the issue?

Comment: What is the value for the property ThreeState?

Comment: ThreeState is false after it claims it is "Checked" in the event handler MessageBox.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a specific problem that will never be any help to others seeing this post in the future.

Answer (score 1):

MSDN says in [CheckBox.CheckState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If the ThreeState property is set to false, the CheckState property
>   value can only be set to CheckState.Indeterminate in code and not by
>   user interaction.

It seems that you need a different approach if you want to execute code only when the CheckState is Checked

You could add another checkbox that is enabled only when the first one is checked

```
private void mfsCheckbox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    checkForExtraStuff.Enabled = mfsCheckbox.Checked;
}

private void previewButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mfsCheckbox.Checked)
    {
        //do basic stuff
        if (checkForExtraStuff.Checked)
        {
            //do extra stuff
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What about the Checked Property value? What would a different approach look like? I've used the CheckBox.Checked property before for this and only now had this isssue...

Comment: Checked could be only true/false so it is not viable for a three state flag. Depending on your requirements it is probably better add another checkbox that stays disabled if the first one is not checked and becomes enabled when the first is checked. At this point the user could set checked also the second checkbox. (seen in numerous configuration forms)

Comment: All I need to determine is if it is checked or not. I resorted to CheckState only because Checked was not working for some reason, that's really what I'm trying to figure out.

Comment: Also, your code won't work because it never enters the first if statement in the PreviewButton event if the CheckBox is checked. Both the Checked and CheckState property show incorrect values.

Comment: I suggest to remove the CheckedChanged event and see what happens

Comment: I only added the CheckChanged event because the if statement wasn't working originally. I just took it out, no change. The CheckChanged event was only to show that it was correctly showing that it was "Checked" when I checked it.

Comment: Difficult to say what's happening. Take a look at this property http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.autocheck(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately my AutoCheck property is set to True, which should update the value of CheckBox.Checked as soon as the CheckBox is clicked. Thanks for the attempt.

Comment: To the downvoter, I was trying to help, thanks

Comment: You got my upvote for all that work.

Comment: @CODe I really have no more idea, the last shot I would do is setting a breakpoint at the event and then using the debugger to proceed step by step to see if something unexpected changes the Checked flag